# does Micro Strategy tool support DB Postgres DB?

Tags: postgresql, microstrategy

Currently we are using microstrategy as a reporting tool  11.1 version and using Oracle DB  -  micro strategy   metadata, Statistics , history all installed in Oracle 
now we are planning to move Db from Oracle to Postgres. just wanted to check if  microstrategy support Potgres DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of certified and supported versions: [Repositories](https://doc-archives.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.11/Readme/content/certified_configurations.htm)

From personal experience I can say PostgreSQL v9,v10 and v11 runs fine as metadata repository. Tested v9-v12 as DWH too, all working without problems.

As far as I remember they didn't deliver the bundled driver in one of the MSTR-versions (2019-something), but that seems to have changed in MSTR-2020 again. Not a showstopper, but something to be aware of.

I am also running PG-11 as repo for History List too, but you definitely won't get help from support for this. OT: They even made me switch from MariaDB to MySQL for a support case (don't really blame them though, it's not certified and that's that).

My last attempt at running Statistics-Repo with PG is a long while ago and it didn't really work out of the box. Don't know what the situation is there. You might have to consider moving to PlatformAnalytics and/or MySQL(/MariaDB) for this too. EM only receives bugfixes from MSTR-2020 onwards, so this seems to be future-proof ([EM discontinued from 2020 onwards?](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/question/0D54400006uVJgiCAG/microstrategy-2019-111-will-be-last-version-to-support-enterprise-manager-2019-readme-says-that-does-it-mean-em-will-no-longer-work-in-the-next-platform-release-or-does-it-mean-microstrategy-will-stop-making-enhancements-in-the-tool))

This mostly reflects our experience, the only certified PG version for MSTR 11.1 is PG-9 and only for the MD-Repo!